# Android; getApplication() returning null, can't see why

Tags: android, android-2.1-eclair

(It's quite late here, so could be overseeing something really simple..)

I've got the following class :

```
public class GlobalState extends Application {
    private Stub stub = new Stub();

    public Stub getStub() {
        return stub;
    }
}
```

and this in my application tag on android manifest..

```
<application android:name="com.jameselsey.observerpattern.GlobalState"
...
>
```

Now, whenever I try to grab this, such as in a Service class, I get a null pointer (gs is null), I'm using the following

```
private GlobalState gs = (GlobalState) getApplication();
private Stub stub = gs.getStub();
```

I've got a similar setup working in another app, so I really can't see why this isn't working since I've based this on the one that does work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you update the application tag in AndroidManifest.xml with your class name?

```
<application android:name=".AppObject">
```

You might find some help [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

Comment: Thanks, but isn't this correct: `<application android:name="GlobalState">` so without . (dot) in name?

Comment: I think it will work without the . (dot) as well, though I remember reading somewhere that it is recommended to use the . (dot).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `(GlobalState) getApplicationContext();`
That's the only method call I use when I use my own application class. You can also just cut the name to `android:name="GlobalState"` (at least in 2.2)